# Unable to check CheckBox state inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

The following is my code...

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillgrid();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lblteachername = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridteachername");
            CheckBox status = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkgridstatus");
            if (status.Checked == true)
            {    
                string q = "insert into teacher (status) values('"+dayList[i].Date+"') where schid='"+dayList[i].SchId+"'";    
            }                
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `if (status.Checked==true)` always returns `false` no matter I check the checkboxes  in the girdview or not.

```
public void fillgrid()
    {
        string q = "select * from teacher where teachername='" + drpteachername.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'  and ('2013-03-01' between date and todate) and '2013-03-31' between date and todate";
        dt = dbo.Getdt(q);
        //NOTE- if you bind gridview with dt, gridview will automatically generate no. of rows equal to the no. of rows returned to dt through the sql query from database.

        abc();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < dayList.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        string teachername = drpteachername.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string month = drpmonth.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string strclass = drpclass1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string section = drpsection1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //string time=drpstarttime1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < dayList.Count; i++)
        {

            Label lbldate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgriddate");
            string fullstring = Convert.ToString(dayList[i].Date);
            lbldate.Text = fullstring.Substring(0, 9);

            //string q1 = "select starttime,endtime from teacher where teachername='"+drpteachername+"', and '"+fullstring+"' between date and todate";
            //dt = dbo.Getdt(q1);
            //int count=dt.Rows.Count;

            Label lblteachername = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridteachername");
            lblteachername.Text = teachername;

            Label lblclass = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridclass");
            lblclass.Text = dayList[i].Class;

            Label lblsection = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridsection");
            lblsection.Text = dayList[i].Section;

            Label lbltime = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridtime");
            lbltime.Text = dayList[i].StartTime.Substring(0, 5) + "-" + dayList[i].EndTime.Substring(0, 5);


        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TeacherName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgridteachername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgridclass" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgridsection" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgriddate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgridtime" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Present">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkgridstatus" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Insert" onclick="Button3_Click" />
                </td>
```

abc() method just fills the List. I hope context is more clear now.

Comment: Why should they have `Checked==true`? I assume you are creating them in `fillGrid` since you `DataBind` it there. So they might be `Checked` when you comment out `fillgrid()`(depends on the context).

Comment: I am filling this GridView from fillgrid(). And then checking rows. Do i need to populate the Grid on the button click without using fillgrid()?

Comment: I am not Binding in on Pageload. I have posted more code, check my edit.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i think i know what i am doing wrong. I will get back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should they have `Checked==true`? You are creating them in `fillGrid` since you `DataBind` it to it's `DataSource`. So they might be `Checked` if you comment out `fillgrid()`.

From the aspx markup and the `Text` of `Buttton3` i see that you want to use it for inserts(use better ID's). Then i don't know why you want to reload the datasource *before* you have inserted anything. Just move `fillgrid` to the end (to reload the Grid after you have inserted).

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //  fillgrid();   <-------------------- from here

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Label lblteachername = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridteachername");
        CheckBox status = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkgridstatus");
        if (status.Checked == true)
        {    
            string q = "insert into teacher (status) values('"+dayList[i].Date+"') where schid='"+dayList[i].SchId+"'";    
        }                
    }

    fillgrid();    // <-------------------- to  here
}
```